# React - Is there a way to check when page is done loading after route change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a loading screen and I want to hide it when a page is done loading but I can only do that on the initial page load. I want to display the loading screen when the user changes route and hide it hide it when the page is done loading.

I want something similar to the [pace.js](https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) library so it can detect when the page is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait some async request for each page, there are few ways:

You can create some global loader and insert it near Router:

```js
<div>
  <Loader />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact> <Home /> </Route>
    <Route path="/users"> <Users /> </Route>
    <Route path="/articles"> <Article /> </Route>
    ...
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Then create custom hook:

```
// useGlobalLoading.js
import ...

export default (isLoading) => {
  const dispatch = ...;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(showLoading());
    return () => {
      dispatch(hideLoading());
    }
  }, [isLoading])
}
```

and then in any component

```js
...

const Users = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useGlobalLoading(isLoading);

  const fetch = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await api.getUsers(...);
      setUsers(response.data.users);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) { ... }
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div>{users ... }</div>
}
```

From other side you can create reusable component Loader, and import it to all components where you have to show it:

```js
// Users.js or Articles.js
return (
  <>
    {isLoading && <Loader />}
    {!isLoading && <div>{users...}</div>}
  </>
)
```